# How to extract the numerical values in the tables

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-value, webmathematica, mathematica-online

[image: Code in Mathematica]

```
TFinal = 30;
TFinal = 30;
Subscript[a, 11] = 0.9;
Subscript[a, 12] = 0.0005;
Subscript[a, 13] = 0.055;
Subscript[a, 21] = 1.7000;
Subscript[a, 22] = 0.075;
Fehlbergamat = {{1/4}, {3/32, 9/32}, {1932/2197, -7200/2197, 
    7296/2197}, {439/216, -8, 3680/513, -845/4104}, {-8/27, 
    2, -3544/2565, 1859/4104, -11/40}};
Fehlbergbvec = {25/216, 0, 1408/2565, 2197/4104, -1/5, 0};
Fehlbergcvec = {1/4, 3/8, 12/13, 1, 1/2};
Fehlbergevec = {-1/360, 0, 128/4275, 2197/75240, -1/50, -2/55};
FehlbergCoefficients[4, p_] := 
  N[{Fehlbergamat, Fehlbergbvec, Fehlbergcvec, Fehlbergevec}, p];
Fehlberg45 = {"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
   "Coefficients" -> FehlbergCoefficients, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
   "EmbeddedDifferenceOrder" -> 5, "StiffnessTest" -> False};
s2 = NDSolve[{D[X[t], t] == 
    Subscript[a, 11] X[t] - Subscript[a, 12] X[t]^2 - 
     Subscript[a, 13] X[t] Y[t] ,
   D[Y[t], t] == -Subscript[a, 21] Y[t] - Subscript[a, 22] Y[t]^2 + 
     Subscript[a, 13] X[t] Y[t],
   X[0] == 10, Y[0] == 5}, {X, Y}, {t, 30}, Method -> Fehlberg45]
Plot[Evaluate[{X[t], Y[t]} /. First[s2]], {t, 0, 30}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed["X[t],Y[t]", Below], 
  PlotRange -> All]
L3 = Table[{t, s2[t]}, {t, 0, 10}] // TableForm
```

Question

1. The outcome of the values are not giving me what I need as seen in the picture.
2. Is it okay to have the same graph or numerical values when using CRK4 and RKF45

Comment: Please explain more clearly just what you problems are.  By the way, use `L3 = Table[Join[{t}, Through[({X, Y} /. Flatten[s2])[t]]], {t, 0, 10}] // TableForm`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for the code. With regards to the problem, I am comparing RK4 and RKF45 hoping to have a better approximation with RKF45 but it seems to me both numerical approximations gives me the same values. Is this correct or something is wrong with my computation?

Comment: There is a problem with your last line. `s2` is not a function, it's a solution of a differential equation. It is a set of rules.

Comment: As a general rule, wrappers such as `TableForm` should not be included in definitions of variables such as `L3`. The wrappers make subsequent use of the variables difficult. Either use parentheses to isolate the definition from the wrapper, e.g., `(L3 = Table[{t, X[t], Y[t]} /. s2[[1]], {t, 0, 10}]) // TableForm` or use `TableForm[L3 = Table[{t, X[t], Y[t]} /. s2[[1]], {t, 0, 10}]]`